# Response filtes in struts 1

Tags: java, struts, struts-1

We are using struts 1.2.4 in our application.
The application currently allows caching of secure(https) pages (cache-control is not enforced).  I want to change that behaviour and add cache-control:no-cache to all the responses.

Does struts provide some framework for setting cache policy globally?

How can i do this?

UPDATE:
The below answer from Bon Espresso worked. I had to add 
"Cache-Control","no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
and Date header to the filter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Filter, configure your filter in web.xml

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>cacheControlFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.package.CacheControlFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>cacheControlFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

And your filter class

```
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Date;

public class CacheControlFilter implements Filter {

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
                         FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletResponse resp = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        resp.setHeader("Expires", "Tue, 25 Dec 1993 23:59:59 GMT");
        resp.setHeader("Last-Modified", new Date().toString());
        resp.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
        resp.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");

        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

}
```

Comment: I tried this. The headers are getting set. But i am able to view the pages by pressing the back button.  Is there any other header i should set?